# How to pass an array to liquid filters on the fly?

Tags: liquid

I have tried the following without success:

```
{{ 'foo', 'bar'   | join: ',' }}
{{ ('foo', 'bar') | join: ',' }}
{{ ['foo', 'bar'] | join: ',' }}
```

I really don't wanna have another line to pass the array into a variable then use it.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The Array needs to come from a Liquid Drop. Liquid does not allow you to assign an Array.

```
{% assign a = [1,2,3] %}
```

will **NOT** work. So even on 2 lines it won't work.

I don't understand your situation but it seems you can just do :) ;) :

```
{{ 'foo,bar' }}
```

or maybe something like (one line also :)):

```
{{ '1|2|3'  | split:'|' | join:',' }}
```